# Increase proxy time out in wildfly server

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-16

How can i increase the proxy time out in wildfly server version 16 ?

I have tried many ways by changing the standalone.xml file but it did not work.

```
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$BadGateway: 502 Proxy Error
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:83) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.serviceclient.RestClient.processRestCall(RestClient.java:46) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.serviceclient.EswitchClient.processRequest(EswitchClient.java:86) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.service.billermgt.impl.BillerMgtServiceImpl.getUserActiveCreditCardList(BillerMgtServiceImpl.java:259) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.service.billermgt.impl.BillerMgtServiceImpl.getUserCardDtoList(BillerMgtServiceImpl.java:241) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.service.billermgt.impl.BillerMgtServiceImpl.getUserBillerList(BillerMgtServiceImpl.java:209) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.service.billermgt.impl.BillerMgtServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2d245c9.invoke(<generated>) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,144 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.service.billermgt.impl.BillerMgtServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da6b8f8.getUserBillerList(<generated>) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.api.billermgt.BillerMgtRestController.postGetUserBillerList(BillerMgtRestController.java:82) ~[classes:?]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.api.billermgt.BillerMgtRestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7e2bd8a4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes:?]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.api.billermgt.BillerMgtRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddfae7a9.postGetUserBillerList(<generated>) ~[classes:?]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
23:46:08,149 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706) ~[jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791) ~[jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,150 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502) ~[?:?]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364) [undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.19.Final.jar!/:2.0.19.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar!/:2.3.3.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar!/:2.3.3.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar!/:2.3.3.Final]
23:46:08,152 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar!/:2.3.3.Final]
23:46:08,154 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
```

I get the 502 bad gateway error.I want to increase the proxy time out in wildfly server.Is it possible to increase proxy timeout in wildfly server.
Can anyone explain how it is done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you call proxy timeout? Are you maybe getting HTTP 504? If so, is there an http server (such as Apache's httpd) acting as a proxy between the clients and the Wildfly, that would be responding with the 504? If so, how are you handling communication between the http server and the Wildfly? modcluster, mod_proxy, mod_jk?

Comment: I am using default http server in wildfly

Comment: I have no idea about modcluster, mod_proxy, mod_jk. I use default http server in wildfly.

Comment: Can you then tell us how you're using Wildfly as a proxy?  A proxy to what?  Is there anything else in front of Wildfly?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting 502 bad proxy gateway error.I think it can be fixed by increasing proxy time out in wildfly server.Is it possible to done increase proxy time out in wildfly server ?

Comment: I see from your stacktrace that your Spring application is the client of a REST service. In the stacktrace it's raising an HTTP 502, which while it could be raised by your application is most likely the response it's getting from the server it's calling, which would be acting as a proxy. If that's the case, it means the server you're calling is OK, but the backend it acts as a proxy of is down. If you still need to increase a timeout, it will likely be configured by Spring (which provides the client implementation here) rather than in Wildfly itself.